# "ActivationsSource" is not a class or namespace name

Tags: c++, visual-c++, scope, compilation, namespaces

I am using a namespace to hold constant variables that I reference regularly, Nothing seems to be wrong until I try to compile the program, then I get

> C2653: 'ActivationSource' is not a class or a namespace name

and

> C3861: 'IdentitySource': identifier not found

My include file looks like this (please mind that i'm not using precompiled headers):

```
// includes.h
#pragma once
#include "pch.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include "CustomTypes.h"
#include "ActivationSource.h"
#include "ThresholdSource.h"
#include "StaticVariables.h"
...
```

the file that generates errors looks something like this

```
// StaticVariables.h
#pragma once
#include "includes.h"
namespace activations
{
    const Activation Identity = ActivationSource::IdentitySource;
    ...
}
```

and ActivationSource.h looks similar to this:

```
// ActivationSource.h
#pragma once
#include "includes.h"
namespace ActivationSource
{
    float IdentitySource; // this is defined in ActivationSource.cpp
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance and I apologise for possibly spelling names differently from time to time.

Comment: There are circular includes. Also you seem to include precompiled header into include file `#include "pch.h"`. Also relying on "include dump" header file makes your code base fragile. It would be better to include header files required by particular file directly into that file.

Comment: You include includes.h, which includes ActivationSource.h, which includes includes.h, etc. In general, it’s bad practice to have a global includes header file, because this will invariably happen.

Comment: This must be the file include problem